# Sending iOS notification after button is pressed on my app

Tags: swift, swift3

Hey there I have a reservation button that creates a reservation and uploads it to my database. Is there a way to create a timer that sends a notification after 15 minutes they press the button?

Comment: More information please.

Comment: so once the button is pressed they have 15 minutes to get to the restaurant. in 15 minutes I want to display an iOS notification that there 15 minutes is up

Answer (score 1):

Use `UILocalNotification` and schedule it `notification.fireDate = whatever time; UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)`